# bypass powershell running error

Tags: powershell

Good Morning

I'm trying to run the powershell script https://github.com/the-xentropy/xencrypt/blob/master/xencrypt.ps1 and both the script and the file I'm trying to encrypt are in the same directory
the steps I followed were

```
Import-Module ./xencrypt.ps1
Invoke-Xencrypt -InFile test.ps1 -OutFile testcrypted.ps1
```

But I got the error

```
Invoke-Xencrypt : Exception calling "ReadAllBytes" with "1" argument(s): "Não foi possível localizar o ficheiro
'C:\Users\DESKTOP\test.ps1'."
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-Xencrypt -InFile test.ps1 -OutFile testcrypted.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-Xencrypt], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileNotFoundException,Invoke-Xencrypt
```

What my be the reason?

Thanks

Comment: I would assume the module has a coding error in it.  You would need to fix the coding error yourself if you want to use the module.

Comment: that doesn't help me at all. You don't provide any clue of what the error my be

Comment: The important part of the error message, that indicates what is wrong, is not in English.

Comment: sorry for that
it says "The file could not be found 'C:\Users\test.ps1'."

Comment: but both the script and the file are in the same directory

Comment: Try using full paths on the parameters.